# How can I add items in the view, but sequentially

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a page with for example personal data, I want to have a Go button for other items such as job data but on the same current page with a Go button (next) and so on...
What is this characteristic called Please provide a link to it, or a brief explanation. (like multiview in old version 'asp.net web form')

I'm using asp.net core

Comment: Do you find [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-action) ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solve by using ajax.

In your controller you have to make a action just like this

```
public JsonResult GetYourData()
{
 //Add your data here. Make a string along with your data like '<h2>Job Data</h2><p>Title:Software-Developer</p>'

 return Json(yourCreatedString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

Now in view you could add an event on the button click, ask for this above action, get the html in string format, and append that to your DOM